# How does pthread_create() work?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Given the following:

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, function, NULL);
```

- What exactly does `pthread_create` do to `thread`?
- What happens to `thread` after it has joined the main thread and terminated?
- What happens if, after `thread` has joined, you do this:

  ```
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, another_function, NULL);
  ```

Comment: I'm being downvoted....why? It's a specific question on programming.

Comment: +1, it is always nice to know about implementation details.

Comment: The good thing about open source is that the source is open. You can always download pthread's source code and check it out.

Comment: [pthread_create](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=34d83f94ade0cef92f6c9a769b7d65c96c8cfe44;hb=HEAD)

Comment: @MatheusMoreira, While editing, you are not supposed to *change* the question itself. If you have more/similar questions, you should post it separately Or post it in the comments.

Comment: @KingsIndian, I did not intend to change the meaning of the question, only to make it clearer and more concise. If it is not appropriate, please feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira, I answered for the original question. Due to your edit, it seems irrelevant now. Don't do it when you have alternative options. I don't want to rollback now because others have answered based on your edit.

Comment: The revisions to my question are much more akin to what I'm looking for. Thanks so much guys, and I'm really sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly does pthread_create do to thread?

`thread` is an object, it can hold a value to identify a thread. If `pthread_create` succeeds, it fills in a value that identifies the newly-created thread. If it fails, then the value of `thread` after the call is undefined. (reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html)

> What happens to thread after it has joined the main thread and terminated?

Nothing happens to the object, but the value it holds no longer refers to any thread (so for example you can no longer pass it to functions that take a `pthread_t`, and if you accidentally do then you might get `ESRCH` errors back).

> What happens if, after thread has joined, you do this:

Same as before: if `pthread_create` succeeds, a value is assigned that identifies the newly-created thread.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that pthread_create will actually make the thread and the thread is executed. If you don't have pthread_join, the main thread will not wait for the thread to finish and just proceed. If you have pthread_join, the main thread will wait for the thread to finish there. Isn't it right?

Comment: That's all true, but I took the question to be about what the function call does to the object `thread`, not about what it does to the thread of execution identified by the object.

Answer (score 2):

pthread_create will create a thread using OS calls. The wonderful things about abstraction is that you don't really need to care what's happening below. It will set the variable thread equal to an identifier that can be used to reference that thread. For example, if you have multiple threads and want to cancel one of them just call

pthread_cancel(thread)

using the right pthread_t identifier to specify the thread you're interested in.

> What happens to thread after it has joined the main thread and
>   terminated?

Before the thread terminates the var thread serves as a key/index to get at or identify a thread. After the thread terminates the value that the key/index pointed to no longer has to be valid. You could keep it around and try to reuse it, but that's almost certain to cause errors.

> What happens if, after thread has joined, you do this:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, another_function, NULL);
```

No problem, since you give it a reference to thread the value of thread will be set to an identifier for the new thread that was just made. I suspect its possible that it could be the same as before, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: How do you know `pthread_join` does not modify the object. The object is opaque. You can not (and should not) know what each of these calls does to the `pthread_t` object that you pass as parameter.  All you know is that it is used to identify a thread within the other `pthread_*` calls.

Comment: @Loki, `pthread_join` takes its `pthread_t` argument by value; it cannot affect its value. It can certainly modify the "object" that the `pthread_t` value identifies, but that's a separate issue, and one that Paul's answer never even mentioned. It's the way way `free` doesn't modify the pointer it gets passed.

Comment: @RobKennedy: You are making assumptions. What if pthread_t was a pointer. Then you can easily modify the object. But we are missing the point. The point is **you do not know (and should not know)** what the functions do to the object. The object is **opaque** for a reason.

Comment: even if pthread_t was a pointer that pointer will not be modified, it's copied into the call. The thing it points to may be modified, but that's where the opaqueness comes in. You have a valid point and I edited the response to try to not get into the discussed problem.