# How should a thread pool be implemented in C?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, threadpool

I'm programming in C++, but I'm only using pthread.h, no boost or C++11 threads.

So I'm trying to use threads but based on one of my previous questions [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434717/how-does-pthread-create-work), this doesn't seem feasible since threads terminate right after completion of its task, and one of the more prevalent reasons to use a thread-pool implementation is to reduce thread-creation overhead by reusing these threads for multiple tasks.

So is the only other way to implement this in C to use fork(), and create a pipe from the main to child processes? Or is there a way to set up a pipe between threads and their parent that I don't know about?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hiding thread creation and having a queue of jobs (function + object) with some wake-up event should do it. Are you looking for some specific behavior?

Comment: Decide whether you want a C or C++ solutions. Whether the underlying library is pthreads (i.e. C only) is much less important than the language for which you want to provide the thread pool.

Comment: If you want [C++ then TBB is a great choice](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799924/thread-wait-for-parent/5799978#5799978

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [thread-safe queue](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) between the threads. Then the threads in the pool will sit in a loop retrieving an item from the queue, executing whatever it needs, then going back and getting another.

That's generally a bit easier/simpler in C++ because it's a little easier to agree on some of the interface (e.g., overload `operator()` to execute the code for a task), but at a fundamental level you can do all the same things in C (e.g., each `task` struct you put in the queue will contain a pointer to a function to carry out the work for that task).

In your case, since you are using C++, it's probably easier to use an overload of `operator()` to do the work though. The rest of the `task` struct (or whatever you choose to call it) will contain any data needed, etc.

Comment: So ideally, the queue would need to be thread safe and use a semaphore with a max val of the max number of threads that I'm going to spawn, right? This implementation seems a bit dirty...I never feel right setting data/containers "out in plain sight", not encapsulated by a class. That's why I asked about a master-child_thread pipe implementation

Comment: Is the overhead of having a parent-child_PROCESS pipe worth data encapsulation?

Comment: @K-RAN: The one I linked (scroll down to the "final code") *is* encapsulated in a class.

Answer (score 3):

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
   const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
   void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

> (...) The thread is created executing `start_routine` with `arg` as its sole argument.

So, you should create a bunch of threads with this function, and have them all execute a function that goes something like

```
void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    WorkQueue *queue = static_cast<WorkQueue *>(arg);

    for (task in queue) {
        if (task == STOP_WORKING)
            break;
        do work;
    }
    return WHATEVER;
}
```

(At the end of input, push *n* `STOP_WORKING` items to the queue where *n* is the number of threads.)

Mind you, pthreads is a very low-level API that offers very little type-safety (all data is passed as `void` pointers). If you're trying to parallelize CPU-intensive tasks, you might want to look at [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

'doesn't seem feasible since threads terminate right after completion of its task' what??

```
for(;;){
  Task *myTask=theCommonProducerConsumerQueue->pop();
  myTask->run();
}
```

.. never return anything, in fact, never return.

Comment: I never thought about that prior to this post, nor did I know about pthread sleep methods; my understanding of threads before this was that they're one-shot things.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it helpful to look at [the source code for libdispatch](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-187.7/), which is the basis for Apple's Grand Central Dispatch and uses thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Threaded Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org) from Intel to accomplish work-queue/threadpool like tasks. A fairly contrived example using TBB 3.0:

```
class PoorExampleTask : public tbb::task {
    PoorExampleTask(int foo, tbb::concurrent_queue<float>& results)
    : _bar(foo), _results(results)
    { }

    tbb::task* execute() {
        _results.push(pow(2.0, foo));
        return NULL;
    }

private:
    int _bar;
    tbb::concurrent_queue<float>& _results;
}
```

Used later on like so:

```
tbb::concurrent_queue<float> powers;
for (int ww = 0; ww < LotsOfWork; ++ww) {
    PoorExampleTask* tt
        = new (tbb::task::allocate_root()) PoorExampleTask(ww, powers);
    tbb::task::enqueue(*tt);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

http://people.clarkson.edu/~jmatthew/cs644.archive/cs644.fa2001/proj/locksmith/code/ExampleTest/threadpool.c

I used google a couple months ago, you should try it.

Edit: it seems maybe you want a group instead.  I was able to create one with some minor alteration of the above so that the worker didn't perform work, but just joined threads.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to integrate this threadpool to event library like libevent. It seems to have own infinite loop that waits for task for thread.