# How to check if thread is "free"

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have 3 threads that working in a while true loop.
I have array of semaphores that can cause threads to wait.

If one of the threads "free" I want it will do some function. How can I make it?

I will try to show the code:
I have 3 doctors and N Patients that waiting for doctor to get him inside
or a doctor that waiting for a Patient.

I tried to get to the relevant section for each of them and just ask if the other one is available.

Patients:

```
get_medic(num);
        while(!flag1){
            if()
        }
        paying(num);
    sem_post(&semPatients[4]);

    printf("I'm Patient #4, I'm paying now");
```

Doctors:

```
while(1){
    while(!flag2){
        if()
    }
    workingNow(num);
    getPay(num);
}
```

It seems to me that is impossible to explain myself
the code is over 200 lines so I will share it all..

Comment: What do you mean by "free"?  Waiting on a semaphore?  If so, just signal the semaphore.

Comment: You seem to describe a *thread pool* scheme. You might want to read about this elsewhere (for example https://nachtimwald.com/2019/04/12/thread-pool-in-c/), or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451992/how-should-a-thread-pool-be-implemented-in-c

Comment: You cannot usefully query the thread’s current state since a thread’s state changes asynchronously relative to your thread—so whatever information you got back might be out-of-date by the time you examine it.  What you can do is post information about what you need done to a (mutex-synchronized) queue and program your threads to pull jobs out of the queue and execute them, whenever they can.

Comment: guys the code is working now but I have deadlock. it need to keep until I press cntl+c. this is the code https://pastebin.com/RHqFBAjf maybe someone can look?